Telerik RadCalendar - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_events') Error
We have removed the AjaxControlToolkit reference as it is no longer required from our solution.  However, one file, where no changes were made, is now breaking, after we removed the AjaxControlToolkit package. This file uses the Telerik RadCalendar control and is breaking during initialization.
Interestingly, the error disappears when the AjaxControlToolkit package is re-added.  The following error is noticed when toolkit package is removed ,
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_events')
at Sys.UI.DomEvent.addHandler (Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?TSM_HiddenField=ctl00_rsmMain_TSM&compress=1&TSM_CombinedScripts=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3a4533c2d0-c52e-4b49-a697-806d77e9914d%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%2c+Version%3d2021.3.1111.40%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d121fae78165ba3d4%3aen-US%3abcb430ee-771a-4d39-a6d4-3550d81a8d67%3a16e4e7cd%3a365331c3%3a88144a7a%3aed16cbdc%3a24ee1bba%3ab2e06756%3a92fe8ea0%3afa31b949%3ac128760b%3a19620875%3a874f8ea2%3af46195d3%3a4877f69a%3a33715776%3a490a9d4e%3abd8f85e4%3a58366029%3a2003d0b8%3a1e771326%3aaa288e2d%3a258f1c72%3ae330518b%3ac8618e41%3ae4f8f289%3a1a73651d%3a333f8d94:6:57366)
at Telerik.Web.UI.RadCalendar.initialize (Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?TSM_HiddenField=ctl00_rsmMain_TSM&compress=1&TSM_CombinedScripts=%3b%3bTelerik.Web.UI%2c+Version%3d2021.3.1111.40%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d121fae78165ba3d4%3aen-US%3abcb430ee-771a-4d39-a6d4-3550d81a8d67%3a59462f1%3aa51ee93e:109:8)
at Telerik.Web.UI.RadCalendar.endUpdate (Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?TSM_HiddenField=ctl00_rsmMain_TSM&compress=1&TSM_CombinedScripts=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3a4533c2d0-c52e-4b49-a697-806d77e9914d%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%2c+Version%3d2021.3.1111.40%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d121fae78165ba3d4%3aen-US%3abcb430ee-771a-4d39-a6d4-3550d81a8d67%3a16e4e7cd%3a365331c3%3a88144a7a%3aed16cbdc%3a24ee1bba%3ab2e06756%3a92fe8ea0%3afa31b949%3ac128760b%3a19620875%3a874f8ea2%3af46195d3%3a4877f69a%3a33715776%3a490a9d4e%3abd8f85e4%3a58366029%3a2003d0b8%3a1e771326%3aaa288e2d%3a258f1c72%3ae330518b%3ac8618e41%3ae4f8f289%3a1a73651d%3a333f8d94:6:53689)
at Sys.Component.create (Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?TSM_HiddenField=ctl00_rsmMain_TSM&compress=1&TSM_CombinedScripts=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3a4533c2d0-c52e-4b49-a697-806d77e9914d%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%2c+Version%3d2021.3.1111.40%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d121fae78165ba3d4%3aen-US%3abcb430ee-771a-4d39-a6d4-3550d81a8d67%3a16e4e7cd%3a365331c3%3a88144a7a%3aed16cbdc%3a24ee1bba%3ab2e06756%3a92fe8ea0%3afa31b949%3ac128760b%3a19620875%3a874f8ea2%3af46195d3%3a4877f69a%3a33715776%3a490a9d4e%3abd8f85e4%3a58366029%3a2003d0b8%3a1e771326%3aaa288e2d%3a258f1c72%3ae330518b%3ac8618e41%3ae4f8f289%3a1a73651d%3a333f8d94:6:55151)
at :4:5
at Sys._Application.add_init (Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?TSM_HiddenField=ctl00_rsmMain_TSM&compress=1&TSM_CombinedScripts=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3a4533c2d0-c52e-4b49-a697-806d77e9914d%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%2c+Version%3d2021.3.1111.40%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d121fae78165ba3d4%3aen-US%3abcb430ee-771a-4d39-a6d4-3550d81a8d67%3a16e4e7cd%3a365331c3%3a88144a7a%3aed16cbdc%3a24ee1bba%3ab2e06756%3a92fe8ea0%3afa31b949%3ac128760b%3a19620875%3a874f8ea2%3af46195d3%3a4877f69a%3a33715776%3a490a9d4e%3abd8f85e4%3a58366029%3a2003d0b8%3a1e771326%3aaa288e2d%3a258f1c72%3ae330518b%3ac8618e41%3ae4f8f289%3a1a73651d%3a333f8d94:6:67025)
at :1:17
at Sys._ScriptLoader._loadScriptsInternal (Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?TSM_HiddenField=ctl00_rsmMain_TSM&compress=1&TSM_CombinedScripts=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3a4533c2d0-c52e-4b49-a697-806d77e9914d%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%2c+Version%3d2021.3.1111.40%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d121fae78165ba3d4%3aen-US%3abcb430ee-771a-4d39-a6d4-3550d81a8d67%3a16e4e7cd%3a365331c3%3a88144a7a%3aed16cbdc%3a24ee1bba%3ab2e06756%3a92fe8ea0%3afa31b949%3ac128760b%3a19620875%3a874f8ea2%3af46195d3%3a4877f69a%3a33715776%3a490a9d4e%3abd8f85e4%3a58366029%3a2003d0b8%3a1e771326%3aaa288e2d%3a258f1c72%3ae330518b%3ac8618e41%3ae4f8f289%3a1a73651d%3a333f8d94:15:4736)
at Sys._ScriptLoader._loadScriptsInternal (Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?TSM_HiddenField=ctl00_rsmMain_TSM&compress=1&TSM_CombinedScripts=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3a4533c2d0-c52e-4b49-a697-806d77e9914d%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%2c+Version%3d2021.3.1111.40%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d121fae78165ba3d4%3aen-US%3abcb430ee-771a-4d39-a6d4-3550d81a8d67%3a16e4e7cd%3a365331c3%3a88144a7a%3aed16cbdc%3a24ee1bba%3ab2e06756%3a92fe8ea0%3afa31b949%3ac128760b%3a19620875%3a874f8ea2%3af46195d3%3a4877f69a%3a33715776%3a490a9d4e%3abd8f85e4%3a58366029%3a2003d0b8%3a1e771326%3aaa288e2d%3a258f1c72%3ae330518b%3ac8618e41%3ae4f8f289%3a1a73651d%3a333f8d94:15:4794)
at Sys._ScriptLoader._loadScriptsInternal (Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?TSM_HiddenField=ctl00_rsmMain_TSM&compress=1&TSM_CombinedScripts=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3a4533c2d0-c52e-4b49-a697-806d77e9914d%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%2c+Version%3d2021.3.1111.40%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d121fae78165ba3d4%3aen-US%3abcb430ee-771a-4d39-a6d4-3550d81a8d67%3a16e4e7cd%3a365331c3%3a88144a7a%3aed16cbdc%3a24ee1bba%3ab2e06756%3a92fe8ea0%3afa31b949%3ac128760b%3a19620875%3a874f8ea2%3af46195d3%3a4877f69a%3a33715776%3a490a9d4e%3abd8f85e4%3a58366029%3a2003d0b8%3a1e771326%3aaa288e2d%3a258f1c72%3ae330518b%3ac8618e41%3ae4f8f289%3a1a73651d%3a333f8d94:15:4794)

Could be a bad import on the page. Could also be your version of telerik needs to be updated. What version are you running currently?
